# The teacher selects 4 students in her class of 20 to be in a public relations photo for the school. How many different groups of 4 are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The teacher selects 4 students in her class of 20 to be in a public relations photo for the school. How many different groups of 4 are possible?

My work:

So in this case we have $4$ spaces, so you count down from $20$.

$20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot 17=116,280$

So the answer is $116,280$.

Comment: Since we are choosing groups, the order of the students does not matter. There are $4\times3\times2\times1=24$ ways to order the $4$ chosen students, so we must divide the result by $24$.

Comment: are you saying 116,280 divide by 24? @player3236

Comment: Yes, that is what player3236 is saying.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

In your count, you are selecting a first person in $20$ ways, a second person in $19$ ways, a third person in $18$ ways, and a fourth person in $17$ ways.  However, the order of selection does not matter, just which students are selected to appear in the photograph. Since there are $4! = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$ orders in which you could have counted the same group of four people, you have counted each group of four people $4!$ times.  Hence, the number of ways for the teacher to select $4$ of her $20$ students to be in the photograph is
$$\frac{20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot 17}{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}$$
By multiplying the numerator and denominator by $16!$, we can express the answer in the form
$$\frac{20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16!}{4!16!} = \frac{20!}{4!16!}$$
Your answer would have been correct if the teacher had also arranged the four students she had selected from left to right.

In general, the number of ways we can select a subset of $k$ objects from a set of $n$ objects is
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
There are $n$ ways to select the first object, $n - 1$ ways to select the second object, $n - 2$ ways to select the third object, and so forth.  There are $n - (k - 1) = n - k + 1$ ways to select the $k$th object since we have already selected $k - 1$ objects.  Thus, we can make an *ordered* selection of the $k$ objects in
$$n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k + 1)$$
ways.  If we multiply and divide this formula by $(n - k)!$, we obtain the formula
$$P(n, k) =  \frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k + 1)(n - k)!}{(n - k)!} = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$$
for the number of [k-permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of a set of $n$ objects, that is, for the number of ordered selections of $k$ of the $n$ objects in a set.

However, when we are interested in selecting a subset of $k$ objects from a set of $n$ elements, the ordered of selection does not matter.  There are $k!$ orders in which we could select the same $k$ objects, so we have counted each subset $k!$ times.  Dividing the number of $k$-permutations of $n$ objects by the $k!$ orders in which we could pick the same subset yields the formula
$$C(n, k) = \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
for the number of $k$-element subsets of a set with $n$ elements, that is, the number of [$k$-combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of a set with $n$ elements.